# Loading Google Charts with AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, charts

I've got a problem while trying to load google charts with jquery ajax, for some reason it creates a redirect loop to the same page.

Here's a part of the code I used:

```
<div id="unique_views" style="float:left;"></div>
<div class="cb"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">  

google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
// Create our data table.
var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
data.addColumn('number', 'Views');
data.addRows([
['Unique Views', <?= $unique_views ?>],
['Total Views', <?= $i ?>]
]);

// Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('unique_views'));
chart.draw(data, {is3D:true, backgroundColor: { fill:'transparent' }, showRowNumber: true, legend:'left',width: 350, height: 240, title: "Unique Views"});
}
</script>
```

I also get sometimes an error in firebug console

google is not defined
 (a,i,e,d)),g&&(f.fragments[a[0]]=h?e:1...a:a+"px")}}),a.jQuery=a.$=f})(window);

Works fine if I try to load the page separately. Any ideas why it would do that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think this line is missing:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi" type="text/javascript"></script>
```